# Angular 6 : passing data from components and push objects in array

Tags: angular, angular6

I created 2 components, one with products and one with shopping cart... They communicate through a service.
Each time I add a product, this product is replaced by the new one ... Technically I would like to "push" the product in an array of products

```
cart: Product[];
product : Product;
subscription : Subscription;


constructor(private basketdataService: BasketdataService) {
    this.subscription = this.basketdataService.onGetBasket().subscribe(
      product => {
        this.product = product;
      });
    console.log("résultat");
}
```

In fact, I wonder how I can push data in this array, avoiding to make it empty at each event.

Comment: You might want to push the product to the `cart` array in the `then` statement. I don't see any problem here!

Answer (score 1):

```
this.subscription = this.basketdataService.onGetBasket().subscribe(
  product => {
    this.cart.push(product);
  });
```

would that work for you?

Comment: It returns : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next

Comment: You need to initialize cart as an array. `cart: Product[] = [];`

Comment: Yep indeed i just needed to initialize it ! i am saved ! thanks !